# Kotlin recursive problem with spring boot hateoas

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-hateoas

I am going through the spring boot tutorial for creating a RESTful service. the example is in Java and I am doing it in Kotlin in IntelliJ IDEA. but, I got a Kotlin Recursive problem when I tried to create a self link with the code attached below.

```
@GetMapping("/employees/{id}")
fun one(@PathVariable id: Long) = repository.findByIdOrNull(id)?.let { employee ->

    EntityModel.of(employee,
            linkTo<EmployeeController> { WebMvcLinkBuilder.methodOn(EmployeeController::class.java).one(id) }.withSelfRel()
    )

} ?: throw EmployeeNotFoundException(id)
```

The IDE complains that `WebMvcLinkBuilder.methodOn(EmployeeController::class.java).one(id)` causes a "Type checking has run into a recursive problem. Easiest workaround: specify types of your declarations explicitly"

Does anyone know the solution for this? or is it not possible to create a self link with Kotlin?

Comment: Just specify the return type `fun one(@PathVariable id: Long): WhateverTypeYouReturn = ...`.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. I thought Kotlin works out the return type itself. They do I need to specify it here?

Comment: The return type of your function cannot be inferred because it depends on its own return type, which is unknown since it wasn't specified. There *are* some cases in which the compiler could technically infer the type of a recursive function but that wasn't implemented.